# Disable one UITableViewCell from being editable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Hey Guys i am currently trying to stopping one tableviewcell from being editable.
But the solutions i found on the internet do not work how they should.
This is the code i use :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            if (indexPath.row == self.results.count+1) {
                return NO;
            }
        }

        return YES;
}
```

The Problem here is that the tableview cell is not editable anymore but it still shows the red 
delete badge if i enable the editingstyle of my tableview like this :

```
- (void) barButtonItemEditPressed: (id) sender
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.barButtonItemDone, nil] animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.barButtonItemCancel animated:YES];
}
```

So what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add edit style as well

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```